# Loop jQuery function to check div position

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a bunch of floated divs and I have a function which checks the position of each of these divs and if the div's left position is 0 then it will add a class to it.

However, when the browser is resized the floated divs change, for example I start off with 4 in a row, then as I resize the browser smaller they go down to 3, then 2, etc.

I want to be able to loop my function so that it continuosly checks the left position of the div to see if it is 0...I can't seem to get it to wrk at the moment, I have tried setInterval and the window resize function, here is my code:

```
$('.box').each(function(index, item){
   if($(this).position().left == 0){
      $(this).removeClass('right');
      $(this).addClass('left');
   } else {
      $(this).removeClass('left');
      $(this).addClass('right');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/icalum/2/edit)* (resize the window to see the changes)

```
function checkPositions(){    
    $('.box').each(function(){
       var myPos = $(this).position().left == 0 ?
       $(this).removeClass('right').addClass('left') :           
       $(this).removeClass('left').addClass('right') ;
    });  
}
checkPositions(); // check on DOM ready


$(window).resize(function(){  // and do it on window resize
    checkPositions();
});
```

Comment: The assignment is not necessary. Also, how is this functionally different from the original snippet?

Comment: @pimvdb The functionality is not missing ... as you can see in the demo :)

Comment: Yes, it works :) I just don't see why the original snippet would not work. +1 anyway

Comment: @roXon Aah where you have called the function straight after the creating the function (on DOM ready), I wasn't aware of that and it now works, you have fixed my problem! You have no idea how much I thank you :)

Comment: @green_arrow You're welcome! Glad it works now! thx to you too